# Label Resolution in DensityPlot with MaTeX

Tags: plotting, labeling

I am using Mathematica 12.0.0.0 on Ubuntu and produced this `DensityPlot` with a `Label` using `MaTex`.

```
fg = DensityPlot[x y, {x, 0, 5}, {y, -0.5, 1.5}, FrameStyle -> Black, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> Full, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
  ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, 50}}, 
  Epilog -> {Text[
     Style[MaTeX["\\zeta\\sigma \\ \\Omega", Magnification -> 2]], 
     Scaled[{.5, 1.05}]]}, 
  FrameLabel -> (MaTeX[#, Magnification -> 20/13] &) /@ {"X", "Y"}, 
  LabelStyle -> {Black, FontSize -> 16}, PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

Now, when I export the plot as pdf without `ImageResolution` using  `Export[".../plot2.pdf", fg]` the resolution of the label is fine, but if I use `Export[".../plot2.pdf", fg, ImageResolution -> 800]` the label becomes jagged as shown below

[image]

I am using `ImageResolution` to get a  good resolution with reasonable  size because sometimes if I use high `PlotPoint` in `DensityPlot` and `Export` it as `pdf` without `ImageResolution` the file size will be too large.

Comment: I remember either 12.0 or 12.1 had major issues with export resolution when it came out, maybe both. At the time I usually fixed it by adding `RasterSize->4000` to the Export command, but then I only ever export to PNG because I long ago gave up exporting to PDF from Mathematica. I’m not sure if it will work, but it’s something to try, I suppose.